# Opentok on streamCreated subscribe makes mobile chrome freeze

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, vue.js, opentok

I am developing webRTC chat on opentok platform and vue.js. While everything is fine on desctop and mobile firefox browser, mobile chrome gets hung up when trying to subscribe to the event.stream. The weird thing is that if I activate developer tools then it will work on mobile chrome as expected so I can not debug error log on this one. I have been racking my brain on this for three days now. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it! Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
    //start the live vicdeo sessiion
    startLivevideoSession: function(session){

        this.call = true; //set call to true

        //initiate opentok session
        this.LiveVideo_session = OT.initSession(session.apiKey, session.session)

        //define on streamcreated method
        this.LiveVideo_session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {

                //this is the problem:
                this.LiveVideo_session.subscribe(event.stream, 'stream_video1', {
                      height: '100%',
                      width: '100%',
                      showControls: true,
                      style: {
                        audioLevelDisplayMode: 'auto',
                        buttonDisplayMode: 'off',
                        nameDisplayMode: 'off',
                        videoDisabledDisplayMode: 'auto',
                        showArchiveStatus: false
                      }
                }, this.handleError)
                //problem ends


            }.bind(this))

        //define on sessionDisconnected method
        this.LiveVideo_session.on("sessionDisconnected", function (event) {

                if(this.call){
                    this.stopVideoButtonPress() //stop on going chat session if any
                    bus.$emit('showModal', "stopLivevideoSessionLeft"); //notify user that other user left the page
                }
            }.bind(this))

        //define connect method
        this.LiveVideo_session.connect(session.token, function(error) {

                if(error){
                    this.handleError(error)
                }else{

                    //if call mode is chat, do not publish chat at all
                    if(this.call_mode != 'chat'){
                        this.LiveVideo_session.publish(this.my_video); //publish my video to chatroom
                    }

                    //if testsession, publish stream also to stream_video1
                    if(this.testSession){
                        this.LiveVideo_session.publish(this.test_publisher)
                    }
                }

            }.bind(this));

        //store session.premium_session to premium_session
        this.premium_session = session.premium_session

        //wait for UI elements to be created on page before OT.initPublisher
        setTimeout(() => {
            //setup my_video
            if(this.call_mode == "audio") //if only audio is selected
                var publisherOptions = {
                  videoSource: null,
                  name: this.connection_setup.stream_video_description+" (vain ääni)",
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '100%',
                  opaque: '1',
                  style: {
                    nameDisplayMode: "on",
                    audioLevelDisplayMode: "on",
                    }
                }
                else
                //setup my_video for videochat
                var publisherOptions = {
                  name: this.connection_setup.stream_video_description,
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '100%',
                  opaque: '1',
                  style: {
                    nameDisplayMode: "on",
                    audioLevelDisplayMode: "on",
                    }
                }

            //if call mode is chat, do not publish chat at all
            if(this.call_mode != 'chat'){
                console.log("call mode"+this.call_mode)
                this.my_video = OT.initPublisher('my_video', publisherOptions, this.handleError)
            }

            //if testsession, publish stream also to stream_video1
            if(this.testSession){
                console.log("call testSession "+this.testSession)
                publisherOptions.name = 'Sinun kuvasi keskustelukumppanin näkemänä';
                this.test_publisher = OT.initPublisher('stream_video1', publisherOptions, this.handleError)
            }

        }, 600);

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be Chrome that freezes, not opentok. See [this chrome 61/android bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769148) which includes a workaround of adding a border-radius

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue!